# Using Docker for Image training in Python (New to this)

Tags: windows, python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

All of my steps have worked very well up to this point. I am on a windows machine currently. I am in the root directory after using the command:

docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel

then followed by a cd /tensorflow, I am now in the directory and it is time to train the images so i jused:

/tensorflow# python tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py \

> --bottleneck_dir=/tf_files/bottlenets \
>   --how_many_training_steps 500 \
>   --model_dir=/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
>   --output_labels=/tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
>   --image_dir /tf_files/

And i get this error:
  File "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py", line 77, in 
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'

I DO already have numpy installed in my python35 folder and it is up to date. Thanks a lot for any help, I am really stuck on this!

Comment: Within your docker container can you see what happens when you do `pip install numpy --ignore-installed` then try again. It's been sometime since I ran this example on docker and I don't remember having any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Remove python 2.7 from Environment  variables and uninstall it . After That install python 3 and run following code to check if numPy is installed properly (It would be as it is included in python 3 package but just to recheck) :-

```
import numpy as np 
a = 'hello world' 
print a
```

and numPy Should Work . Link The Folder again by

```
docker run -it -v (folder path)  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

after that run

```
docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're planning to use Python 3, I'd recommend `docker run -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel-py3` (Numpy is installed for python3 in that container). Not sure why Python 3 is partially installed in the latest-devel package.